# NDK no such directory or file error

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to compile `.so` files in Android, first issue is when I directly use `gradle` it runs perfectly but no `.so` files are generated, so I resorted to calling `ndk` by myself, I made a few changes to my `gradle.build` file now it looks like my `:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nemo.lungu.receiptor"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled false


    ndk
            {
                moduleName "Scanner"
                stl "stlport_shared"
            }
}
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files location to libs
    jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
}

// call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
    }
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
```

}

When I compile my code it just gives me an error to say `ndk` encountered an error so I resorted to method 3; compiling the `.so` files manually, my `Android.mk` files looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include .../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := Scanner

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := scan.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -lm -llog -landroid
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and `Application.mk` looks like:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-15
```

My new error now that it cannot find `sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk`, am running ndk from cmd as follows

1. Open cmd and navigate to ndk directory
2. run the `ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=full/path/to/project APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=full/path/to/project/Android.mk` so if my project is `Mario`in root of my C directory it would be `C:/mario/`

Anyone have an idea on how I can get passed this error?

Comment: my code now complies, except only with `mips` and `x86` it fails with `armeabi` and `armeabi 7`